# border with down arrow using css

Tags: css

I have a requirement like below. [image]

I am able to go through https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/ website and generate triangle. I want to know how to attach it to a border and get the desired dimension of height 10px and width of 40px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the `position: relative;` of the parent div and `position: absolute;` of the child div in which you want to make the arrow.

Main thing by which the arrows are made is [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transform) property.

It is working properly. But here the size of the arrow is just 2x that you want.

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
.line {height: 20px; border-bottom: solid 2px #000; margin-top: 100px; position: relative; z-index: 1;}
.arrow {content: ""; position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%); height: 20px; width: 80px; z-index: 2; background-color: #fff;}
.arrow .pin {width: calc(50% + 5px); height: 2px; background: #000; display: inline-block; float: left; transform: rotate(25deg); transform-origin: 0 0;}
.arrow .pin:last-child {transform: rotate(-25deg); transform-origin: 100% 0; float: right; margin-top: -2px;}
```

```html
<div class="line">
 <div class="arrow">
  <div class="pin">
   
  </div>
  <div class="pin">
   
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

And it is with `40px x 10px` size of arrow.

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
.line {height: 20px; border-bottom: solid 2px #000; margin-top: 100px; position: relative; z-index: 1;}
.arrow {content: ""; position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%); height: 10px; width: 40px; z-index: 2; background-color: #fff;}
.arrow .pin {width: calc(50% + 3px); height: 2px; background: #000; display: inline-block; float: left; transform: rotate(25deg); transform-origin: 0 0;}
.arrow .pin:last-child {transform: rotate(-25deg); transform-origin: 100% 0; float: right; margin-top: -2px;}
```

```html
<div class="line">
 <div class="arrow">
  <div class="pin">
   
  </div>
  <div class="pin">
   
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried implementing this. It works fine in chrome. In FF the arrow looks thinner when compare to border. Any solution for it?          https://jsfiddle.net/w9rkzm5h/

Comment: Just add this rule in css `@-moz-document url-prefix() {.arrow .pin { height: 2.2px; } }`. This would work only in firefox. Updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/w9rkzm5h/1/).

Comment: Anything to put for IE or any other browserS?

Comment: Yes! You can find [here](https://www.wired.com/2010/02/browser-specific_css_hacks/). If you are facing problem on other browser's also.

Comment: Any online tools to test my page for other browsers? As i don't have opera and safari.

Comment: It would always be better to have browsers installed in your own PC, but nevertheless I found [this](https://www.powermapper.com/products/sortsite/checks/browser-compatibility/) and [this list](https://www.keycdn.com/blog/browser-compatibility-testing-tools/) of tools for your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty straightforward.

**Step 1:** You give the `position: relative;` property for the div to which you want to add the arrow.

**Step 2:** add the CSS arrow: `<div class="arrow-down"></div>` And apply a `position: absolute;` property to it so that you could position it as required.

So, if you had a div with the class box, this is what you would do:

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color:red;
  margin: 30px auto;
  position: relative;
}

.arrow-down {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #f00;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
   <div class="arrow-down"></div>
</div>
```

Here's a fiddle for the same: https://jsfiddle.net/t2ne282z/

Comment: arrow comes on top rather then bottom

Comment: You'll just need to modify the position attribute top: to bottom: in that case; here's an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t2ne282z/

Comment: I checked and see that it has color or red. arrow should be transparent and the line on which arrow will be on, the line should not be show.